# Filepond mixed content error in production

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7, filepond

I am having the next error when i try to upload a file using filepond. I have
filepond and filepond's plugins in package.json:

```
"filepond": "^4.13.7",
"filepond-plugin-file-poster": "^2.2.0",
"filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^4.6.4",    
"vue-filepond": "^6.0.2"
```

the message in my console is the next one:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mydomain/posts/create' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://mydomain/imagespost'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

My project is hosted in heroku using heroku/php and heroku/nodejs as builpacks.

My process setup for filepond is the next one:

```
    process: {
        url: PROCESS_DELETE_ROUTE(),
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            "X-CSRF-TOKEN": document.querySelector('input[name="_token"]')
                .value,
        },
        onload: (response) => {
            const parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);
            // we set the name of the hidden inputs as fileinput[] because in that case all the filenames are gonna be send and not just the last one
            document.body
                .querySelector(".filepond--data")
                .childNodes.forEach((elem) =>
                    elem.setAttribute("name", "fileupload[]")
                );
            return parsedResponse.filename;
        },
        onerror: (response) => {
            response.data;
        },
        ondata: (formData, data) => {
            return formData;
        },
    },
```

Where PROCESS_DELETE_ROUTE return the url depending on which path i am at the moment:

```
const PROCESS_DELETE_ROUTE = () => {
    switch (route) {
        case "posts":
            return `${window.origin}/imagespost/`;
        case "contents":
            return `${window.origin}/imagescontent/`;
    }
};
```

I tried console logging the PROCESS_DELETE_ROUTE's return and looks ok, is `https://mydomain`

Comment: it can be you are doing a pre-flight request before the actual request, because you use axios "withCredentials". To check it, on Chrome: Inspect->Network. 

Check how many requests are sent to the target endpoint

Comment: Two requests, the first one got canceled and the second one blocked with the status of blocked:mixed-content.

Comment: Without the `withCredentials` flag is the same behavior

Comment: You should investigate the method of the first request and why it get canceled. 
Also, I don't understand why you use return `${window.origin}/imagespost/` to get the base url, usually you set in your environment variables

Comment: That was a test, i had it just with the relative path at first (`/imagespost/`) and was exactly the same behavior

Comment: I solved that part, was the last '/' at /imagespost/. Now i am bringing the absolute path when i am not in local env. I have some issue with `Image source not readable` now but is a different story, thank you!

Comment: Great! If the image has a dynamic :src I suggest to load the images from the cdn, 'cause if they are in the assets folder, it gets harder

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but i think the problem was the server has not persistency of data, then, each time i was trying to verify if the image was stored, paradoxically i was creating a new instance of the VM deleting the files i stored in the last step. Cloud Storage was my solution

Comment: Great. Cloud storage will avoid bigger problems if you horizontal scale in the future too!